# Create a simple google books api

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

I'm currently trying to create a simple google books api using javascript. However, when I use the console log, nothing shows. I'm still new at this so any help will be appreciated.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $("#myform").submit(function(){

var search = $("#books").val();
if(search == '') {
  alert("Please enter something!")
}

else {
  var url = '';
  var img = '';
  var title = '';
  var author = '';

  $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search, function(response){

    console.log(response);

    //for(let i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

      //title=$('<h5 class="center-align black-text">' + response.items[i].volumeInfo.title + '</h5>');
      //author=$('<h5 class="center-align black-text"> By:' + response.items[i].volumeInfo.authors + '</h5>');
      //img=$('<img class="aligning card z-depth-5" id="dynamic"><br><a href=' + response.items[i].volumeInfo.infoLink + '><button id="imagebutton" class="btn red aligning">Read More</button></a>');

      //url= response.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;

      //img.attr('src',url);

      //title.appendTo("#result");
      //author.appendTo("#result");
      //img.appendTo("#result");

    //}

  });

}
 });

 return false;

});
```

Comment: double check your output, I just copy paste your `$.get()` and callback and i get results from the `console.log()`  -> https://jsfiddle.net/ae5o1bpv/1/

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e900476d5d4e077206f1a450cb7ebf9d i am confused!!

Comment: post your jsfiddle project url

Comment: I actually figured it out. My application was refreshing the page as I pressed the search button. I just added .preventDefault() line of code to stop this from happening and now it works!

Comment: so make an EDIT and label it SOLVED

Comment: I cannot accept my own answer until tomorrow. Thanks Simon.

Comment: @SimonDehaut - that's not the way this site works... :) - the "solved" is implied by the answer, even if it's not accepted.  We don't bake info like that into the titles.

Answer (score 0):

My application was refreshing the page as I pressed the search button instead of taking the input. I just added .preventDefault() here to stop this from happening:

```
$("#form").submit(function(x) {
    x.preventDefault();
var search = $("#books").val();
if(search ==='') {
    alert("Please enter something!")
}
```

Comment: Greetings, please add a slightly mode detailed version of your answer. I know what you did, but, will others know? I'm sure you didn't just add `.preventDefault()` randomly in your code and it magically worked.

Comment: Just added a more complete solution. Thanks for letting me know.